# read boolean default option from environment variable using click

Tags: python

In Click, one can use boolean flags like [this](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/options/#boolean-flags):

```py
import sys

@click.command()
@click.option('--shout/--no-shout', default=False)
def info(shout):
    rv = sys.platform
    if shout:
        rv = rv.upper() + '!!!!111'
    click.echo(rv)
```

However, how does one bind the *shout* level to the existence of the environment variables `SHOUT` or `NO_SHOUT` as default value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the [docs](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/options/#values-from-environment-variables), you can pass the `envvar` parameter.

```
@click.option('--shout/--no-shout', default=False, envvar='SHOUT')
```

However, this will check `SHOUT` looking for a true/false value. I don't know of a clean way to check for the *existence* of two different environment variables, like you asked. (What would happen if they were both set?)

Answer (score 0):

Use `os.environ` and check if it contains `SHOUT`:

```py
import sys
import os

@click.command()
@click.option('--shout/--no-shout', default=False)
def info(shout):
    if not shout and "SHOUT" in os.environ:
        shout = os.environ["shout"]
    rv = sys.platform
    if shout:
        rv = rv.upper() + '!!!!111'
    click.echo(rv)
```

(Not tested as I'm not a `click` user, but should give you a starting idea)

Comment: ``click`` works using decorators, and their arguments; this might be a solution, but this is not how ``click`` is designed. Thanks anyway.